Unable to Access Policies in Azure Portal while permissions have been extended to the User
I myself am the Global Administrator and Owner of the Resource Group and Key Vault, but I am unable to "Access Policies" in Azure Portal. I have even gone into to give myself further permissions but still it shows me the same screen. What should I do?

User Access snapshot

The Azure Subscription, Resource group and keyvault all have been assigned permissions but the same screen keeps on showing. I have logged in and out as well but to no avail.

From the Microsoft documentation:

Azure Key Vault offers two authorization systems: Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC), which operates on Azure's control and data planes, and the access policy model, which operates on the data plane alone.

Your first screenshot indicates that your key vault is using role-based access control. If you want to use access policies, you need to switch the permission model:

Open "Access configuration" under "Settings"
Select "Vault access policy" as permission model
Save the changes


yeah i figured that but can't access policies be turned on with RBAC or is it either one of the two?

Azure RBAC and the vault access policy model can be used simultaneously on the same Key Vault.
However, keep in mind that, access policy model, native to Key Vault and considered legacy, controls access by assigning specific permissions to security principals at the Key Vault scope.
In contrast, RBAC model, built on Azure Resource Manager, provides centralized access management by creating role assignments with defined permissions and scopes.
